# wso2 API retry mechanism in throttling

Tags: wso2, throttling, replay, retrypolicy

I'm newbie on WSO2 platform. 
I wanted to know how messages are stored and replayed when we exceed the quota. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how messages are stored and replayed when we exceed the quota.

The messages are not stored and not resent by api gateway itself. If quota is exceeded, the gateway returns a fault (exception with an error code 900800, here I may be mistaken).

It is task of the client to retry / resend the message